# Monitoring directory with VB Script

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm using the code below to capture a file created in a directory:

```
strComputer = "."
strQueryFolder = Replace(strFolder, "\", "\\\\")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &     strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery ("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN " & nFrequency & " WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent='Win32_Directory.Name=""" & strQueryFolder & """'") 

Do 
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    strNewFile = objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
    arrNewFile = Split(strNewFile, "=")
    strFilePath = arrNewFile(1)
    strFilePath = Replace(strFilePath, "\\", "\")
    strFilePath = Replace(strFilePath, Chr(34), "")
    strFileName = Replace(strFilePath, strFolder, "")
    strTempFilePath = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\TEMP.M4A"

    'Do something with strTempFilePath 

Loop
```

The problem is that the script is capturing the file while it is being written to the directory.

How to identify the completion of writing the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember that i made à Vbscript like that , you can take a look at this code

I hope that can help you and give you more idea.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso,Message,Message2,Msg,intInterval,strDrive,strFolder,strComputer,objWMIService,strQuery
Dim colEvents,objEvent,objTargetInst,objPrevInst,objProperty,ws,LOG_FILE_PATH,LogFile,Chemin,MonTableau
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strComputer = "." 
Chemin = Parcourir_Dossier()
MonTableau = Split(Chemin,"\")
LogFile = MonTableau(UBound(MonTableau)) & ".log"
LOG_FILE_Path = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%AppData%") & "\" & LogFile
intInterval = "2"
'****************************************************************************************************
Function Parcourir_Dossier()
    Dim ws,objFolder,Copyright
    Copyright = "[ © Hackoo © 2014 ]"
    Set ws = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = ws.BrowseForFolder(0,"Choose the folder to watch for "_
    & Copyright,1,"c:\Programs")
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
    Parcourir_Dossier = objFolder.self.path
end Function
'****************************************************************************************************
Chemin = Split(fso.GetAbsolutePathName(Chemin),":")
strDrive  = Chemin(0) & ":"
strFolder = Replace(Chemin(1), "\", "\\")
If Right(strFolder, 2) <> "\\" Then strFolder = strFolder & "\\"
'Connexion au WMI
Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:" &_ 
"{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_ 
strComputer & "\root\cimv2" )
'La chaîne de la requête
strQuery =  _
"Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent" _
& " Within " & intInterval _
& " Where Targetinstance Isa 'CIM_DataFile'" _
& " And TargetInstance.Drive='" & strDrive & "'"_
& " And TargetInstance.path='" & strFolder & "'"
'Exécutez la requête
Set colEvents = _
objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery(strQuery)  
Do 
    Set objEvent = colEvents.NextEvent()
    Set objTargetInst = objEvent.TargetInstance
    Select Case objEvent.path_.Class 
'Si c'est le cas de la création de fichier ou d'un événement de suppression et afficher
'juste le nom du fichier
    Case "__InstanceCreationEvent" 
        Message = DblQuote(objTargetInst.Name) & " is created !"
        Message2 = String(10,"*") & Now & String(10,"*") & vbCrLf & Message & vbCrLf & String(70,"*")
        Call Log(LOG_FILE_Path,Message2)
        'MsgBox Message2,VbInformation,Message
    Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent" 
        Message = DblQuote(objTargetInst.Name) & " is deleted !"
        Message2 = String(10,"*") & Now & String(10,"*") & vbCrLf & Message & vbCrLf & String(70,"*")
        Call Log(LOG_FILE_Path,Message2)
        'MsgBox Message2,VbInformation,Message
'Si c'est le cas de la modification du fichier,comparer les valeurs de propriété de la cible et de l'instance précédente
'et afficher les propriétés qui ont été changé comme la taille et LastModified
    Case "__InstanceModificationEvent" 
        Set objPrevInst = objEvent.PreviousInstance
        For Each objProperty In objTargetInst.Properties_
            If objProperty.Value <> _
            objPrevInst.Properties_(objProperty.Name) Then
            Message = "modified file :        " & vbCrLf &_
            objTargetInst.Name & vbCrLf &_
            "Property :       "_
            & objProperty.Name & vbCrLf &_
            "Last Value : "_
            & objPrevInst.Properties_(objProperty.Name) & vbCrLf &_
            "New value :      " _
            & objProperty.Value
            Message2 = String(10,"*") & Now & String(10,"*") & vbCrLf & Message & vbCrLf & String(70,"*")
            Call Log(LOG_FILE_Path,Message2)
            'MsgBox Message,64,DblQuote(objTargetInst.Name)
        End If    
    Next
End Select 
Loop
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Log(strLogFileChemin,strLogContent)
Const APPEND = 8
Dim objFso,objLogFile
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not objFso.FileExists(strLogFileChemin) Then objFso.CreateTextFile(strLogFileChemin, True).Close
Set objLogFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strLogFileChemin,APPEND)
objLogFile.WriteLine strLogContent
objLogFile.Close
End Sub 
'**********************************************************************************************
```