# Monitor a directory for added files

Tags: python, batch-file, vbscript, monitor

I've written in .vbs .bat and .au3 before, so I know a little about scripting. What I'm after is a file (in any of the above languages) that will monitor a directory (Let's just say "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder") for files (only .html), and then, when a new file is added it will run a new batch file. My only necessity for this is that it runs in the background, with no command window, from what I know and what I've read, .bat won't allow this, and I can't seem to figure out how to do this with .au3 (AutoIt). I'm totally open to new languages, the "inotifywait" from python was suggested, but I've never written in python. All other questions I've read have been for servers, but I just want this all locally done. If someone could please either provide a script for this, or point me towards a link, question, help file or anything else so I could learn this, that would be amazing.

```
@echo off
setlocal
:start
set inputFolder=%1"C:\Users\Zac\Dropbox\SoundCloud"
set extension=%2html
IF EXIST %inputFolder%\*.%extension% GOTO exists
goto end
:end
goto start
:exists
timeout 70 > NUL
call Random.bat
goto start
```

Is my script so far, this works, kind of, this requires me to press a key before continuing, and requires me to do so every time we go to :start, and has a command window.

Comment: Take a look at this vbscript ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509587/monitoring-directory-with-vb-script?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Since you are operating in windows environment you could try the task scheduler. If you are insisting on making this a scripting problem, try using the schtasks command within a batch file.

Comment: Do you have tried a search on Stack Overflow before? See how many questions and answers a simple search with [monitor directory add](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=monitor+directory+add) already returns. Add `[vbscript]` or `[python]` or `[batch-file]` to find solutions specific to one of those script languages. BTW: Using only a batch file is no good idea as batch processing is not designed for event triggered tasks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "cmd /k dir c:\windows\*.*", 0, false
```

This starts a hidden command prompt (the `0`).

If you want it all in vbs see `wscript.sleep` command and here's how to delete, test, and copy files. Also how to start a program.

```
Set Sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FileExists("C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\nethack-360-win-x86-2\bonD0.O") then fso.deletefile "C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\nethack-360-win-x86-2\bonD0.O"

If fso.FileExists("C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\nethack-360-win-x86-2\David%20Candy-David.NetHack-saved-game") then
    fso.copyfile "C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\nethack-360-win-x86-2\David%20Candy-David.NetHack-saved-game", "C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\nethack-360-win-x86-2\David%20Candy-David - Copy.NetHack-saved-game"
else
    fso.copyfile "C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\nethack-360-win-x86-2\David%20Candy-David - Copy.NetHack-saved-game", "C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\nethack-360-win-x86-2\David%20Candy-David.NetHack-saved-game"
end If

sh.run """C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\nethack-360-win-x86-2\NetHackW.exe""", 1
```