# DIR: Find files with certain extensions on network drive

Tags: file, cmd, count, find, counting

I would like to count all files in a directory and it's subdirectories on a network drive using Windows commands. But I only want to count files with certain extensions [text based files like txt, rtf, doc, docx].

How would I do that in a performant and fast way?

I tried several ways combining *dir /s \networkpath... | find ...* but I always stumble upon different problems.

Comment: `Dir /s "C:\Folder\*.ext1" "C:\Folder\*.ext2"`. You must specify the full path to the starting directory for each extension.

Comment: @Noodles This seems to work great! Thank you so far. One thing, though: I noticed the search is running very fast in general but sometimes stops at random files for 2-3 seconds. I can't identify if those are files with big size or what might be the cause. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Folders not in the disk cache will take a lot longer to access than folders in the cache. Folders are special files with a list of files in that folder. Run the command a second time when all folders should be in the cache and compare the speed.

Comment: Does the same as before. I noticed that it always takes longer for two specific files. Not random files as I thought first. Those files are around 5KB in size and can't find anything suspicious.

Comment: Does it just take a long time to find them because it is searching places where it doesn't find anything. Be more selective on where you search for what. Each starting folder gets searched for each extension - so multiple times.

Comment: Seems like so. Maybe there is just not another file coming for a while that matches the search. Anyways. Thank you alot! I wish I could mark a comment as the answer.

Comment: The thing is that this directory changes quite often, so I can't be more selective.
Except there is one folder which I like to exclude from the search as I don't need it's content and the folder is quite big.

Comment: `dir /s "\\Server\Share\folder\*.*" | findstr /i /v /c:"FolderToBeExcluded | Findstr /I /r "ext1 ext2"` How about this. See `Findstr /?`.

Comment: If you are waiting for files there are other solutions. See my answer here for ideas (it is from my favourites so I don't actually know what it says as I have lots of sample progs like this) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509587/monitoring-directory-with-vb-script

Answer (score 0):

You cant count all files in a directory with certain extensions with something like this:

dir /s /b \ippatht*.opr |find /c "\"

Comment: [How to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). 
Add more details to justify your answer.